# Burp Extension Development

Tags: burp

Does anybody know of a way to test if the burp scanner has completed when developing burp extensions?

I am developing a burp extension that hooks into the scanner and i would like to display my results after the scanner has completed. I do not know how to test if the scanner has completed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following works from within the Burp Extender Jython Shell.  Hope it helps.

```
import jarray

callbacks = Burp._callbacks
myRequest = Burp.history[0]
myHost = myRequest.host
myPort = myRequest.port
myByteArray= jarray.array(myRequest.raw, 'b')

testScan = callbacks.doActiveScan(myHost, myPort, 0, myByteArray)

# int showing percentage complete
print testScan.percentageComplete
```